# MetaMask total USD balance including all coins

Tags: metamask

I wonder if it's possible to show total USD balance of MetaMask wallet, including every single coin added there as custom token. I don't see that option in MetaMask, it doesn't even show me BNB or ETH as USD (just 0.00$) and these are very popular.

I would like to know total balance as USD (convert each coin to USD and sum it) and balance for every single coin one by one. Is there any site or tool for this? I think this should be a core functionality, so there must be some other site that offers this after connecting a wallet, or I'm misunderstanding something crucial here.

Comment: I usually just use Etherscan for that.

Comment: Also [Zerion](https://zerion.io/) and [Zapper](https://zapper.fi/).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's been develop by the Metamask team
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6999